# 2 Rows and 3 columns using bootstrap in Django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to iterate multiple posts through a loop, into 2 rows of 3 items.
Currently my code looks like this

```
{% for post in post.all %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">

      <div class="caption">
        <h3>{{ post.title }} - {{post.assignment_level}}</h3>
        <p>by {{post.author}} from {{post.pub_date}}</p>
        <h4>{{post.assignment_body}}</h4>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Read...</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock%}
```

this gives me one column of 6 posts.
How do I split them in to 2 rows of three posts.

Really been googling this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
{% set count = 0 %}
{% for post in post.all %}
    {% if count == 0 %}
        <div class="row">
    {% endif %}
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">

            <div class="caption">
                <h3>{{ post.title }} - {{post.assignment_level}}</h3>
                <p>by {{post.author}} from {{post.pub_date}}</p>
                <h4>{{post.assignment_body}}</h4>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Read...</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% set count = count + 1 %}
    {% if count == 3 %}
        </div>
        {% set count = 0; %}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
{% endblock%}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is creating multiple rows for each posts. Hence all your elements are coming in separate rows.

You can do something like this.

```
<div class="row">
    {% for post in post.all %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">

                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>{{ post.title }} - {{post.assignment_level}}</h3>
                    <p>by {{post.author}} from {{post.pub_date}}</p>
                    <h4>{{post.assignment_body}}</h4>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Read...</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thx, Now you showed it, I could see, that I was making separate rows. Would have never de-bugged that one :)

Comment: Glad. Standard Convention is to upvote, accept and close the answer.